# ASP.NET COMPLEX Script problem; How can I make a combination of TagList with DatePicker?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, datepicker

Well I would like to have something special in my ASP.NET Core application, which I know it requires a very custom and complex Script to do so.

Let's say I have a model code like this one, which has a DateTime List:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace C.Models
{
    public class Cdates
    {
        [key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public List<DateTime> dataTims { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And in my view I would like to have something similar to this, as an Interface:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/o20VD.png

Ok so I'm going to try to explain the picture.
I would like to have something that is like a combination of a DatePicker plus a TagList field.

Basically, it loads the calendar and allows me to click on the days, just like the DatePicker that comes by default in Asp.Net, but I want that when I click on a date, instead of simply taking a specific date and assigning it to the field, I would like that this add said date as an element in the TagList field, and that every time I click on a new Date, this add the new Date as a new tag on the Tag List, and if I click on the X from the tag, I remove said Tag from the group.

So, eventually, this will generate a group of dates, which I clicked on, which are gathered in the mentioned field.

And what I would like is effectively, that this data will be passed as a List of DateTimes to the Controller, so my code does something with the chosen dates, a List  element which is loaded from the View.

I would also like this to include the extra function, of letting me click on the corner of a week from the calendar, and this automatically chooses the 7 days which make up that week, loading those 7 days in the TagList, as seen at the bottom of my picture.

And as a final detail, that the field for the Taglist is relatively well *high* so it doesn't look bad if I load 31 days there.

I know that I am looking for it is quite complicated and specific, but is it possible a script code on the view for do this, right? One of the kind:

```
(document).ready(function () {

        var select = $('select[multiple]');
        var options = select.find('option');

        var div = $('<div />').addClass('selectMultiple');
        var active = $('<div />');
        var list = $('<ul />');
        var placeholder = select.data('placeholder');

        var span = $('<span />').text(placeholder).appendTo(active);

        options.each(function () {
            var text = $(this).text();
            if ($(this).is(':selected')) {
                active.append($('<a />').html('<em>' + text + '</em><i></i>'));
                span.addClass('hide');
            } else {
                list.append($('<li />').html(text));
            }
        ----etc
```

And besides Script, the minor question would be if I should include any special code in the controller for this to work?

And Ok I know that I am possibly asking for something very complicated to do, but I have no idea of how even start to write a Script code that allows this, but I don't lose anything by asking for help. Or maybe there is some example of something quite similar that mixes both DatePickers and TagList?

Comment: I don't think anyone would want to read the entire question. Make your question as short and clear as possible.

Comment: @Rena Hey thank you very much, this really helped me and it was what I needed! Sorry I didn't answer earlier, I was busy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use MultiDatesPicker for jQuery UI:

```
<form asp-action="Test" method="post">
    <input id="mdp-demo" name="datelist">
    <input type="submit" value="create"/>
</form>
@section Scripts
{
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-multidatespicker/1.6.6/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-multidatespicker/1.6.6/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.css" />
    <script>
        $('#mdp-demo').multiDatesPicker();
    </script>
}
```

Backend:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Test(string datelist)
{
    string[] datestrs = datelist.Split(new char[] { ',' });
    return View();
}
```

Reference:

https://dubrox.github.io/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/

Result:

[image]